# GCP - App Engine Endpoints - Performance ISSUE

Tags: java, performance, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Do you guys use the Google Cloud Platform, specifically the APP ENGINE ENDPOINTs for professional/production purposes? Asking because I am not comfortable with response time. It´s taking too long to perform simple http POST requests like registering an users with only e-mail and password (saving in a DATASTORE). In this URL you will find the register form, let me know what you guys thing about the response time, is it acceptable?

https://filiperebollo1986.appspot.com/register.html

My Java code is quite simple. Only instantiate an user object with email and password which does´t have any special encrypting algorithm. Naturally for the registering purpose I need to check if the user already exists and after that save the object in the DATASTORE. I can ensure that the problem is not in my front-end apps because takes too long in the iOS e Android apps too.

POST:

https://filiperebollo1986.appspot.com/_ah/api/igardenendpoints/v12/saveProfile.

```
{
    "userEmail": "response_time",
    "password": "123"
}
```

Response:

> 200
>
> Show headers

```
{
    "messageText": "User successfully created!",
    "messageNumer": 0,
    "kind": "igardenendpoints#resourcesItem",
    "etag": "\"9e-bXvBAIkMzDxg9PvVcUBMIXB0/_RzWmXdehTtOTMg1Y7MhIvXy5-k\""
}


   public Message saveProfile(ProfileForm profileForm) {

    Message message;
    String userEmail = profileForm.getUserEmail();
    String password = profileForm.getPassword();
    String displayName = profileForm.getDisplayName();

    Profile profile = ofy().load().key(Key.create(Profile.class, profileForm.getUserEmail())).now();

    if (profile == null) {

        if (displayName == "") {
            displayName = extractDefaultDisplayNameFromEmail(profileForm.getUserEmail());
        }

        profile = new Profile(userEmail, password, displayName);
        message = new Message("User successfully created!", 0);
    } else {

        message = new Message("User already exists!", 1);
    }

    ofy().save().entity(profile).now();
    return message;
}
```

Comment: any numbers/stats?

Comment: Yes, almost 2 sec...

Comment: always or just once? I mean how many request you made to calculate this number? on a fresh instance or hot?

Comment: igardenendpoints.saveProfile executed moments ago time to execute: 1950 ms

Comment: second: igardenendpoints.saveProfile executed moments ago time to execute: 536 ms

Comment: third: igardenendpoints.saveProfile executed moments ago time to execute: 3287 ms

Comment: using the API explorer...

Comment: yes, some of this numbers looks to large. but you need at least 30-40 requests to make any conclusions

Comment: It's still possible that the problem is in the code, but as we don't see the code we need to find out if this issue really exists. also, in google console you can see what api calls took most time for the request, that's very usefull

Comment: I will manage to put the code here...

Comment: all the code currently posted is not relevant to the issue. revise datastore concepts as it is totally possible to do this under 200ms in datastore.

Comment: I have calls that read/write hundreds of entities return under 500ms. So the problem is not with the datastore. We can certainly help you optimize your code, and there are many useful questions/answers on SO already. Welcome to the community!

Comment: Just upload the API code, the Domain(Profile, Message) classes are simple as assigning the variables values, there are no rules/checks behind them...

Comment: Anyone can help me with that? @AndreiVolgin I posted my java code...